# How to better modularize the ViewPager order/tab names

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-tablayout

I have a `ViewPager` that works well, but I want to make it a little better.

Right now in my `PagerAdapter` class, in the `getItem` method I use a switch statement:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            TabFragmentChicken tabChicken = new TabFragmentChicken();
            return tabChicken;
        case 1:
            TabFragmentFish tabFish = new TabFragmentFish();
            return tabFish;
        ...
```

And then over in my activity class, I set the tabs name like so:

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Chicken"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Fish"));
...
```

Is there a way I can better modularize this? For instance if I wanted to change the order of the tabs I'd have to change both the switch statement and the tab names. Is there another class or structure I can use to keep it all in one place so I only need to update one thing and not have to bother with the switch/adding tab text changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Object that will hold the title and the fragment, then use a list of this Object within your adapter. Here is a small way of implementing it:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import com.chahinemouhamad.parrrot.home.recent.RecentFragment;

public class HomePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
  private final PagerFragment[] pagerFragments;

  public HomePagerAdapter(final FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

    pagerFragments = new PagerFragment[] {
        new PagerFragment("item 1", RecentFragment.newInstance()),
        new PagerFragment("item 2", RecentFragment.newInstance())
    };
  }

  @Override public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
    return pagerFragments[position].fragment;
  }

  @Override public int getCount() {
    return pagerFragments.length;
  }

  @Override public CharSequence getPageTitle(final int position) {
    return pagerFragments[position].title;
  }

  class PagerFragment {
    public final String title;
    public final Fragment fragment;

    public PagerFragment(String title, Fragment fragment) {
      this.title = title;
      this.fragment = fragment;
    }
  }
}
```